# What are some alternative forms of if > then relationships?

Tags: if-statement, relational-database

Traditional if > then relationship in pseudo code:

```
if (x>y) {
then print "x is greater than y."
```

}

There are also relational databases.

Or just visual if>then tables. A visual table representation.

There are also tree or hierarchical structure if>then programming aids.

I'm looking for any and all alternatives and flavors of if>then constructs, but preferably practical ones. Since most humans are better at using and remembering visual constructs (tables vs raw code) than symbolic constructs, I'm looking for the most intuitive way to theoretically construct an if>then rule engine, graphically.

Note: I'm not trying to implement this, I'm just trying to get an idea of what could theoretically be done.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I've interpreted the question correctly.

Everything eventually boils down to comparisons, its just a matter of breaking up these comparisons in manageable chunks for humans. There are many techniques to reduce if-thens, or at least transform them into something easier to understand.

One example would be polymorphism. This frees the programmer from one instance of if/then (basically a switch statement). Another example is maps. The implementation of a map uses if/thens, but one might pre-populate the map with all the data and use one logical piece of code instead of using if/then to differentiate. This moves to a data-driven approach. Another example is SQL; it is just a language, a higher level construct, that enables us to express conditions and constraints differently. How you choose to express these conditions is dependent on the problem domain. Some problems work well with traditional procedural programming, some with logic programming, declarative programming etc. If there are many levels of nested if-thens, a state machine approach might work well. Aspect-oriented programming tries to solve the problem of duplicated code in modules that doesn't belong specifically to any one module; a concern that "cross-cuts".

I would do some reading on [Programming Paradigms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_paradigm). Do lots of research and if you run into a recurring problem, see if another approach allows you to reduce the amount of if-thens. Most times someone else has run into the same problem and come up with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit broad and we could ramble from logical gates to mathematical functions. I'm going to focus on this particular bit:

> "I'm looking for the most intuitive way to theoretically construct an if>then rule engine, graphically".

First, two caveats:

1. The best representation depends on the number of possible rules. What works for 3-4 rules probably won't work for 30-40.
2. I'm going to pretend that `else` conditions don't exist.

If "X then Y" boils down to: one condition and one instruction whose execution depends on the condition. Let's pretend `X -> Y` means that "If X is true then Y is executed". Let's create two sets: one is `C` that contains all the possible conditions. The other one is `I` which contains all the possible instructions.

With this is mind, `X ∈ C` and `Y ∈ I`. In your specific case, can `Y ∈ C` (can Y be a condition)? If so, you have nested ifs.

Nested ifs can be represented as chains of conditions joined by `and` operators:

```
if (x > 3) {
  if (y > 5) {
    # do something
  }
}
```

Can be written as:

```
if (x > 3 and y > 5) {
  # do something
}
```

If you're only thinking about code then the latter can become problematic when you have many nested conditions, but when you go graphical, nesting (probably using tree-like structures) can look cluttered while chaining usually looks like a sequence of instructions (which I think is better).

If you don't consider nesting (chaining) in your rules, then connecting elements (boxes, circles, etc) from `X -> Y` is trivial way to work. The representation of this depends on how graphical you want to get (see the links below for some examples).

If you're considering nesting then three random ideas come to my mind:

1. Venn Diagrams: Visually attractive, useless for more than 3-4 conditions. They have a good fit with database representations. See: http://share.mheroin.com/image/3i3l1y0S2F39
2. Flowcharts: Highly functional and easy to read, not too cumbersome to create. Can get out of hand with 10+ elements. See: http://share.mheroin.com/image/2g071j3U1u29
3. Tables: As you mentioned, tables are a decent way to represent conditionals as long as you can restrain the set of applicable rules. This is an example taken from iTunes: http://share.mheroin.com/image/390y2G18123q. The "Match [all/any] of the following rules" works as a replacement for `if/else`.